# invalid mscorlib exception in custom security attribute c'tor

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, windows-xp, iis-5, windows-authentication

I'm trying to implement my custom security attribute. It's very simple for now

```
    [Serializable]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false)]
    public class SecPermissionAttribute : CodeAccessSecurityAttribute
    {
        public SecPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction action) : base(action) { }

        public override System.Security.IPermission CreatePermission()
        {
            IPermission perm = new PrincipalPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted);
            return perm;
        }
    }
```

For some reason I've got an exception in the attribute c'tor

```
System.IO.FileLoadException occurred
  Message=The given assembly name or codebase, 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll', was invalid.
  Source=WcfRoleProviderTestService
  StackTrace:
       at SecLib.SecPermissionAttribute..ctor(SecurityAction action)
       at WcfRoleProviderTestService.Service1.GetData(Int32 value) in D:\TestProjects\WcfRoleProviderTestService\WcfRoleProviderTestService\Service1.svc.cs:line 19
  InnerException:
```

The dll is signed. It seems to me like a security issue but I'm not sure. By the way I tried to use PrincipalPermissionAttribute and it works fine.
Forgot to say, I'm using VS 2010, FW 4.0, the attribute is concumed in the WCF service
I'll be very glad to get some help.

My service configuration is the following

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="c#" targetFramework="4.0" />

    <roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true" cookieName=".ASPROLES"
      defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add connectionStringName="Service1" applicationName="InfraTest"
          writeExceptionsToEventLog="false" name="MyRoleProvider" type="SecLib.MyRoleProvider, SecLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=798c04e15cff851a" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

  </system.web>

<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBindingConfiguration" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="524288">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfRoleProviderTestService.Service1"
               behaviorConfiguration="BasicHttpServiceBehavior" >
        <endpoint name="BasicHttpEndpoint"
                  contract="WcfRoleProviderTestService.IService1"
                  address="WcfAuthenticationTest"
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBindingConfiguration" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost/WcfRoleProviderTestService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="BasicHttpServiceBehavior">
          <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="UseAspNetRoles"
            roleProviderName="MyRoleProvider" impersonateCallerForAllOperations="true" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I've got the error both on Windows XP, IIS v5.1 and on Windows Server 2008 R2 IISV7.5 only if the WCF service is configured to use Windows Authentication (see the configuration above). On more interesting fact is that the error occured only if the attribute is used with the `System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand` security action.

```
[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Allowed)]
[SecPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand)]
public string GetData(int value)
{
      string userName = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Name;
      return string.Format("You entered: {0}, User {1}", value, userName);
}
```

Other options work fine.
Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't seem to repro the problem.  Is the attribute declared in your service project or in a separate DLL?  When you say that the DLL is signed, which DLL is signed and what kind of signature (strong name or authenticode) is it?  Also, to what part(s) of your code have you applied the attribute?

Comment: Hi @Nicole, I tried both, a separate dll and the service dll, the result is the same. For now, in order to make it simple, the attribute is defined in the same dll as the service, and the dll is signed with a string name (*.snk file). The attribute is applied to a Service method (implementation, not contract).

Comment: I still can't repro the problem.  How are you hosting the service?  Also, have you made any changes from the default behaviours, activation, etc.?

Comment: Hi @Nicole, thank you for helping me. The answer is yes, i've made changes, I use windows authentication with custom role provider which is not in use yet.

Comment: I've added the configuration to the question. I've tried to comment the provider section, the result is the same. By the way, PrincipalPermissionAttribute works fine with no problems, unfortunatly its functionality is not enough for me

Comment: Hi @Nicole, I decided to check the configuration step by step from the begining. I payed itention that I had an exception only when I add Window Authentication

<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">     <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="Windows" /> </security> for binding

<serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="UseAspNetRoles"                       roleProviderName="MyRoleProvider"                       impersonateCallerForAllOperations="true" /> for behavior
I succeeded to run the code on Windows Server 2008 R2 twice but than the error came back

Comment: Unfortunately, I still can't repro the problem.  Could you please provide a minimal but complete sample (http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/complete.html) in which you can repro the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a help of one of my colleagues, the problem has been soleved. I'm not sure what the exact reason of the exception was but it seems to be a compilation issue. When I changed the project type from web application to web site wich is compiled at run time according it's  pool definition (64 or 32 bit) it started to work fine.